# Display image from SP list on infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I created a request form in Infopath that users can use to request supplies. My solution was to create a repeating section that has a list box of items from a Sharepoint list. I would like to see if I can also display the attachment that is tied with the item. Can this be done in Infopath?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    1.  Select where on Infopath form you want the image displayed 
    2.  Insert ‘image’ from controls panel 
    3.  Right-click on the image control, and select ‘picture properties’ 
    4.  Select the icon next to the ‘XPath’ field 
    5.  Select ‘show advanced view’ 
    6.  Select ‘+’ next to the ‘Attachments’ folder, and select ‘:attachmentURL’ 
    7.  Click ‘OK’
    8.  Click ‘OK’ 
    9.  Save and publish the form
```